# Javascript - Retrieve background image url is null

Tags: javascript, background-image

I want to retrieve background image from this link https://20.detik.com/sosok/20220108-220109036/tangis-rindu-pak-ogah-pada-pak-raden but the output is null

```
<div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdnv.detik.com/videoservice/AdminTV/2022/01/08/Tangis_Rindu_Pak_Ogah_Pada_Pak_Raden-20220109001335-custom.jpg?w=400&amp;q=80&quot;); background-color: black; background-size: contain;"></div>
```

here is my code

```
    var c = document.createElement("html");
    c.innerHTML = content;
    body = c.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    //get poster url
    filmimg = body.getElementsByClassName("container-video")[0];
    div = filmimg.querySelector("div #detikVideoIdNewId video .vjs-poster");
    console.log(div);
```

Comment: You are not giving us all the information we need. Where is this running? Some kind of web scraping tool?

Answer (score 0):

Try computedStyle

```js
const style = window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector(".vjs-poster")
)
console.log(style["backgroundImage"])
```

```html
<div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdnv.detik.com/videoservice/AdminTV/2022/01/08/Tangis_Rindu_Pak_Ogah_Pada_Pak_Raden-20220109001335-custom.jpg?w=400&amp;q=80&quot;); background-color: black; background-size: contain;"></div>
```

Comment: it showed an error for me.   throw new TypeError(`${context} is not of type 'Element'.`);
        ^

TypeError: The provided value is not of type 'Element'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `querySelector` is off. Try this:

```js
let backgroundImage = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-poster")[0].style["background-image"];
let url = backgroundImage.split("\"")[1];
```

Comment: it showed an error for me. TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Comment: I have made changes to my code above.

Comment: Understood. I added more of my code defining `body` and `filming`

Comment: It still showed an error. TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style'). My variable content contains an HTML page source. While I tried to inspect element and view page source, they have a different source. When I open with view page source it doesn't contain .vjs-poster . Does it impact my code?

Comment: I think you need to specify where and how you're running this JS code. If you go the URL listed above, right click, select `Inspect`, and run this code in the console it works fine. I went ahead and reduced my code though since you can accomplish the same thing in 1-2 lines.